# select with NEW in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have written a MySQL trigger but it gives a syntax error:

```
create trigger trg_check_row_exists before insert on charges
for each row
begin
    if exists (select 1 from charges c where c.product_id = new.product_id) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Record already exists in charges table';
    end if;
end
```

The syntax error is coming form the WHERE clause. What is the issue with this?

**UPDATE**

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger trg_check_row_exists before insert on charges
for each row
begin
    if exists (select 1 from charges c where c.currency_value_id = new.currency_value_id) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Record already exists in charges table';
    end if;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

had to add `DELIMITER` and`$$`. now it's working.

Because there are multiple statements with `;` MySQL client threat them as separate statements and not consider trigger as single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a trigger for this.  Instead, use a unique constraint/index:

```
 create unique index unq_charges_productid on charges(product_id);
```

This will ensure that only one product can be in the table at a time.

Also, your logic would seem to indicate that you want `exists` rather than `not exists`.

Comment: yes it should be `exists` :) actually I have other columns to be checked. some of them have null values. so I cant use `unique index`